# Unsubscribe from calendar in iOS calendar app

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, ical

I accidentally subscribed to a calendar I don't want on my iPhone and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. I can easily hide it in the Calendar app, but I can't find how to unsubscribe from it.

I searched online for how to unsubscribe, and it said that if I click on the "i" button on the right of the calendar, there would be a "delete calendar" button, but there isn't. I can find the "delete calendar" button for the "personal" and "work" calendars that are there by default, but not on the calendar I want to delete. All I can do when I click on the "i" button is rename the calendar, change its color and choose if I want to get notifications from it.

[image]

("Prenumererad" means "subscribed")

I also tried to delete the calendar online from http://icloud.com, but it didn't show up on iCloud. Since I use a Google account, I also tried to delete it online from Google calendar, but it wasn't there either.

I also tried deleting and reinstalling both the Calendar app and the app that installed the unwanted calendar, but it was still there after I reinstalled the app. The app which installed the calendar only has a "subscribe to calendar feed" button (which was the one I accidentally clicked on) and no "unsubscribe from calendar feed" button.

How do I unsubscribe from this calendar?

Comment: Not sure this is entirely relevant, but this is always a good link to check when dealing with google calendars in iCal: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect

Comment: @JBallin No, it's not in that list either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Local Subscriptions

Calendars you subscribe to locally can be removed under Settings > Passwords & Accounts > Subscribed Calendars > [the calendar in question] > Delete Account.
[Sourced from MacRumors](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/subscribe-to-calendars-on-iphone-ipad/).

### Cloud Accounts

Calendars you subscribe to via Google Calendar can be removed [from the website](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings).

Calendars you subscribe to through iCloud can be deleted from the info view.